# Recover files from ruined Xubuntu using Windows

Tags: boot, usb, windows, xubuntu, files

I'm pretty new to Linux and Ubuntu. I have installed a bootable (persistent) Xubuntu on a USB stick, and it worked - I booted from it and used Xubuntu happily.

But now it is ruined - I'm not sure why, but the computer stopped responding a few times so I manually turned it off and disconnected the USB stick, and ever since the Xubuntu won't load (black screen, keyboard/mouse won't respond).

I would like to do 2 things right now:

1. Copy some files (a folder) I've created, to my Windows computer (in order to edit those files in Windows).
2. Back up my settings (configuration and customization) in order to later embed them in a different Xubuntu installation. (Especially the *panels*)

Is it possible to do those things with Windows (7)?

---

**Update:**

*ext2read log file:*

```
No of disks 0
No of disks 0
ysicalDrive0
index 0 ID 27 size 27262976 
index 1 ID 7 size 204800 
index 2 ID 7 size 460924928 
Scanning \\.\PhysicalDrive1
index 0 ID C size 29259776 
index 1 ID 5 size 1044482 
index 4 ID 82 size 1044480 
No of disks 2
Scanning \\.\PhysicalDrive0
index 0 ID 27 size 27262976 
index 1 ID 7 size 204800 
index 2 ID 7 size 460924928 
Scanning \\.\PhysicalDrive1
index 0 ID C size 29259776 
index 1 ID 5 size 1044482 
index 4 ID 82 size 1044480
```

Comment: No OS likes being turned off. USB sticks particularly so, I've always assumed due to the slower write speeds. There are threads here on how to get out of it better; like [this one.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes).

Comment: Thanks @MarkWilliams ! I'll use this arcticle when the computer gets stuck. I'm not even sure that that is what happened - the screen went black (but still on!) and the computer was on even though no mouse/keyboard shortcuts seemed to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also suggest you to boot from another Linux DVD or USB stick (e.g. the one you used for installing Ubuntu). If your partitions on your live stick aren't damaged, it should be no problem rescuing the files.

Maybe you have to log into your second rescue system as root (better: run file explorer as root, e.g. in Ubuntu: `gksu nautilus`), because I think otherwise you don't have full access on all of the files (second system respects file rights of the first). I'm not sure, but I experienced this on a dual boot Ubuntu/Kali machine. But you have to mount the partitions you want to explore before that under the normal account. It must be possible as root too, but this way its easier.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks ByteCommander and @Minos ! I'll try it later. What about my second question - which files are the ones that contain the Xfce *panel* configuration? It's really important for me to copy that also, I spent 30 minutes on customizing those panels :)

Comment: A quick look at google taught me this: (source: [link](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=7671))  Try copying all files and folders in '/home/your_username/.config/xfce4', from the old partition to your new system. This should include all xfce-settings. Thanks for the reputation, by the way!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out as soon as I reinstall Xubuntu on my USB stick.

Answer (score 1):

The default installation of Ubuntu uses the ext4 filesystem, which Windows can't read without installing third party drivers (see also the other answer of The Thunder Chimp). Personally I think you are much better off making a second liveUSB with Xubuntu to recover your files and then do the reinstall.

Comment: I agree, that would be simpler

Comment: But where are those files even stored? In Xubuntu, they are located in "Home", but when I try to browse the files of the USB stick from windows I see some folders, and I can't even search for my files... Windows Explorer's search doesn't find anything.

Comment: Yes, Windows can't see the files you're looking for, they are in an ext4 partition that gets mounted when you boot Xubuntu. That's why I suggest using a second usb stick with Xubuntu, which can read your files on the other usb stick.

Answer (score 0):

A number of Windows programs will allow you to access Linux files. I've never tried getting some files off a live USB, but if the data isn't corrupted it should work. A simple program is Ext2Explore, which you don't even have to install. I would go for that. More sophisticated programs can embed themselves in Windows explorer and allow write access. But in my experience they are longer to get working.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer - sounds like what I need.
I've tries ext2read, (downloaded the .exe file from SourceForge), but it shows no files, blank window. I even copied the files from the Stick to the Desktop and scanned again, still nothing. (note: I did open it "as administrator"). I'm attahing the contents of the .log file in the question (not enough space here)